# Laravel : Search with same table if search request available

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a simple query to get post and it returns all post.I have implemented search on same query.

My query for getting all data :

```
  $userPostDetails    = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
                                ->offset($offset)
                                ->limit($limit)
                                ->whereStatus("Active")
                                ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
                                ->whereIn('status', $demand_or_supply) 
                                ->orderBy('id','desc');

                            if($title) {
                                $userPostDetails->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($title) {
                                    $query->where('title','=', $title);
                                });
                            }
$userPostDetails->get();
```

It search complete data what condition apply on `product` table. But if  I want to search within a same table which is `posts` table how can I do   this separately like `$title` so whenever I gt data in `$search` this separate query perform.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `when` operator, documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses), he when function checks if the variable is empty or null and if it exists, it will execute the callback and add a query condition :

```
->when($demand_or_supply, function($query) use ($demand_or_supply) { 
    $query->whereIn('status', $demand_or_suppl);
})
->orderBy('id','desc')
->when($title, function ($query) use ($title) {
    $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) use ($title) {
        $query->where('title','=', $title);
    });
})
->get();
```

**EDIT :**

Or you can use a default value like that :

```
->whereIn('status', $demand_or_supply ? $demand_or_supply : 'default')
```

Comment: `posts` table how can i achieve thius ? if search parameter available

Comment: In your exemple you are already querying posts table, did you mean products table ?

Comment: talking about `posts` table , yes I am querying posts table but if in my condition `whereIn('status', $demand_or_supply) ` , but what when in search parameters `$demand_or_supply is Null` .You get what i want to say ?

Comment: Ok so for each of your parameters, you can use the when function or maybe a default value :
`->when($demand_or_supply, function($query) use ($demand_or_supply) { $query->whereIn('status', $demand_or_suppl); })`

or

`->whereIn('status', $demand_or_supply ? $demand_or_supply : 'default')`

Is that helping you ?

The when function checks if the variable is empty or null and if it exists, it will execute the callback and add a query condition.

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172751/discussion-between-javed-and-julien-metral).